# How to show tickets used by Java Kerberos enabled applications

Tags: java, kerberos

I have a Java app running in Tomcat under Windows that offers Kerberos authentication and uses the JVM GSS-API implementation.

I'd like to take a look at the tickets obtained by the app, but it seems the (native) Windows klist tool and the Java klist tool don't show them.

The user the app is running under has no krb5cc* file in its home dir, so I'm stuck.

Is there a way to look at the tickets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's not writing service tickets back to the native credential cache whether it's Windows or Unix. It stores tickets in the private subject only.

Comment: Ok, so I'd have to code something up to show them? Theres no way to make it export them into some krb5cc* file?

Comment: What is your actual goal with that?

Comment: We've got a problem with a webapp (Alfresco) that is 2-tier http, with a repository and a presentation layer. 

The UI layer has to authorize itself via kerberos, so is krb service and client at the same time. Some users sometimes can't access the server, and I strongly suspect the UI tier to be at fault, because login to the repository tier usually works fine.

I think the server can't renew its initial krb ticket, so after the ticket expires, login is no longer possible. Strangely, this affects only some users.

Comment: OK, why don't you rely on credential delegation? This is actually the default way to go with a kerberized multi-tier environment.

In your case, the UI layer **needs** a keytab to access the repo layer, do not rely a M2M on a credential cache.

Comment: Thats actually how it works, sorry if I got you confused. There is a keytab, and the password for the principal has to be specified in the application's configuration. The principal has delegation activated.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is still not clear. What you should/can do: Have the client send you a service ticket, make your machine account `TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION`, accept the security context, retrieve the delegated credential and contruct a new context with  which you will send requests to your repo layer. Is this what you do or what you want?